# FFMPEG, C++, Memory leak, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

So I've built this app that consumes an IP cameras rtsp feed and does fun things with it, however I have a small memory leak that I have only just now pinned down.

If I just run this

```
while (av_read_frame(input_format_context, &input_packet) >= 0) {}
```

It will just grow'n grow'n grow ... So what am I missing?

Am using a windows port of ffmpeg and my version is 58.9.100.0
Could it be a leak in FFMPEG itself?

Comment: Check the manual: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61 It's pretty clear about what you need to free.

Comment: Wow .. for the two downvotes... Thanks alot for ... being the awesome persons you are, keep it up and say hi from me on 4chan. Later.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> If pkt->buf is NULL, then the packet is valid until the next
>   av_read_frame() or until avformat_close_input(). Otherwise the packet
>   is valid indefinitely. In both cases the packet must be freed with
>   av_packet_unref when it is no longer needed.

Something like this?

```
 AVPacket *pPacket = av_packet_alloc();
 if (!pPacket)
 {
    logging("failed to allocated memory for AVPacket");
    return -1;
 }

 while (av_read_frame(pFormatContext, pPacket) >= 0)
 {
    auto  response = decode_packet(pPacket, pCodecContext, pFrame);
    if (response < 0)
        break;
    }

    av_packet_unref(pPacket);
  }
```

PS: Don't be a victim of cargo cult, research the source code. this is in no way a complete example. There are working projects that use ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks, actually that was my original code, I just kept removing code until I was at the barebone and it was still leaking.. The code snippet you suggest still leaks. Thanks for the effort though.
PS: I realize that FFMPEG is industry standard so obviously it is working, however, I am not using daily and is using the windows port .. I was contemplating if something got lost in translation.

Comment: are you sure it's leaking here? are you sure it's a leak at all, not a system-based preallocation effect (runtime doesn't free allocated memory to OS for later use). How do diagnose the leak? See: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2534

Comment: Well you caught me again, I am sorry for not being a C++ grandmaster, I hacked C/C++ in my young days but pay my bills coding Java for a long time...
I observe taskmanager memory allocation, and it just .... keeps on growing.

Comment: @MrSmith Well, nix `cat /proc/meminfo` or windows  minimal taskmanager show total reserved+used memory. On windows, resource usage display (on WIn7, I don't know its analog on Win10) could show the difference. Otherwise you need some dynamic checking software or library, which would track allocation\deallocation calls. MS Compiler had some low-level tools, but I'd better go after dedicated tool

Comment: It might be more productive to use a memory debugger like ASAN or Valgrind on your unit tests so you can detect *in isolation* whether any part of your code leaks.